# How do you prove that all countable, densely ordered sets without endpoints are isomorphic to the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I've looked online for a proof of this and have found several references to Canter's isomorphism theorem and the "back-and-forth method." However, I haven't been able to find any explicit proofs anywhere. I've only found outlines of how such proofs might work, such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method). Unless I'm misunderstanding something, proofs like the one linked above indicate how to construct an order-preserving bijection but don't actually prove that it is one. Does anyone know of a proof that involves explicitly proving the property of isomorphism?

Comment: The linked article constructs the function explicitly. What exactly prevents you from filling details yourself? It should be straightforward.

Comment: @freakish I don't mean to be rude, but if I understood how to write the proof that I'm asking for help with, then I wouldn't be asking for help... I probably should have been clearer in my original question, but I don't really understand how the function used in that article is a bijection, which is why I was looking for an explicit proof.

Comment: @user93824 which part is unclear to you, why the function on wikipedia is injective, why is it surjective or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have two countable linear orders $A$, $B$. Both are unbounded and dense. The author writes down

$$A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$$
$$B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$$

The construction of a order preserving bijection $f:A\to B$ goes like this. The author first says that it is the same as constructing a sequence of pairs $P$ by the following procedure

- Step 1. $(a_1,b_1)\in P$
- Step 2. Let $i$ be the smallest $i$ such that $a_i$ is not paired with anything from $B$. Pair $a_i$ with any $b_j$ such that $b_j$ is not yet paired with anything and the ordering is consistent. Meaning if $a_s<a_t$ then the corresponding $b$s are in the same order. Such choice can always be made because until this step we only chose finitely many elements, and $B$ is infinite, dense and unbounded from both sides.
- Step 3. Similarly let $j$ be the smallest $j$ such that $b_j$ is not paired with anything from $A$. Analogously consistently pair $b_j$ with some $a_i$.
- Step 4. Go back to step 2.

Now each step 2 and each step 3 reduces both $A$ and $B$ by one element. And since in step 2 we pick "smallest (in the sense of index) element of the remaining" we can easily conclude that every element of $A$ will be ultimately be picked. Analogously step 3 guarantees that every element of $B$ will ultimately be picked up. In fact element at index $i$ (in both sets) will be picked up after at most $i$ iterations of the loop. This means that if our function is well defined, then it is surjective.

Being well defined follows from the observation that every $a\in A$ will eventually be picked up, and will be picked up exactly once. Being injective follows from the observation that every $b\in B$ is picked exactly once.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.